# How to check if GTLServiceCalendar has authorised an User or no in iOS

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api

Basically, I am using this code to fetch google events. I need to know whether it has already authorized an User or not. That way I can avoid a server call.

```
-(void)getGoogleCalendar{    
GTLServiceCalendar *calendarService = self.calendarService;    
GTLQueryCalendar *calendarListQuery = [GTLQueryCalendar queryForCalendarListList];
[calendarService executeQuery:calendarListQuery completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLCalendarCalendarList * object, NSError *error) {       
    for (GTLCalendarCalendarListEntry *calendar in object.items) {
       [self getEventsForTheGivenCalendar:calendar.identifier];
    }        
    }];
}
```